# Swift bug or something wrong with this Struct

Tags: xcode, swift, struct

I starting with swift, but always something wrong appear

I did this struct :

```
 struct Needs {
    var name:String
    var qts:Double
}
```

And made an array :

```
let qq =   [ Needs(  name: "rice",  qts: 3.0 ) ,
             Needs(  name: "shoes",   qts: 1.0 )  ,
             Needs(  name: "water",   qts: 1.0 )  ]
```

but the result is Wrong :

```
([PEScenatic.Needs]) $R0 = 3 values {
  [0] = (name = "", qts = 0)
  [1] = (name = Swift.String @ 0x7ff9dd903db0, qts = 0)
  [2] = (name = Swift.String @ 0x7ff9dd982390, qts = 0)
}
```

Edit: Is really a bug in 32bit mode ,but  in 64bit iOS emulator is everything OK

Comment: I cannot reproduce it either. How do you come by the result? Do you try it in a Playground or a println statement in a project, etc..?

Comment: Probably just a figment of lldb. It's not very good at this sort of thing (arrays).

Comment: I close, restart xcode ... and continues ... but only in emulator ipad2 , iphone 4s mode ( 32bit ) in 64bit mode, is OK  in playground is OK